# Panel grounding

Tags: electrical-panel

I have an old zinsco panel(I know...) in my garage.  It's a 100 amp service panel not a sub panel.  The panel is grounded to a ground rod and bonded to pipes. There is also bonding strap from the panel to the  bar in the panel. Should that strip stay connected to the neutral/ground bar in the panel?  Both neutrals and grounds share the same bar in this panel. Thanks

Comment: I trust you when you say that 'you know' about the Zinsco, but how would you feel if your house burned because you ignored a known safety hazard?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the main bonding jumper should stay in place.